# htaccess RewriteRule 500 error - loop

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Question is simple
I want to rewrite 
http://www.mydomain.com/test123.com
like
http://www.mydomain.com/details.php?domain=test123.com

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /details.php?domain=$1 [L]
```

Thanks.

Comment: And code that gives you 500 error is...

Comment: Ofc it's possible, but you should post code that gives you trouble, there's no code in your question.

Comment: I used: RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /details.php?domain=$1 [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your rewrite URL. You can use following `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index.php)?$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/details.php$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /details.php?domain=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It will rewrite `http://www.mydomain.com/test123.com` to `http://www.mydomain.com/details.php?domain=test123.com`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But unfortunately I get "Internal Server Error" message

Comment: Try now. I've updated to make it simple. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that; rewrite is ok but now, mainpage (index.php) goes to details.php too.

Comment: @user3620931 Try updated answer

Comment: As much as I understand, I must write my all pages url which I use with %{REQUEST_URI}. So, these pages will not rewrite. Thank you very much again :)

Comment: most welcome but please next time while asking question clarify all scenarios and don't forget to include code you've tried :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I want to ask one more question: Can we define %{REQUEST_URI} as all .php including pages?

Comment: Yes, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*\.php)?$`